# Google Sheet "across spreadsheets you've created"

Tags: google-sheets, importdata

I have an error for an `importdata` function

```
Error
Loading data may take a while because of the large number of requests. 
Try to reduce the amount of IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED or 
IMPORTXML functions across spreadsheets you've created.
```

Does Google Sheet mean the number of functions across the current workbook? Or all workbook that I have ever created in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Across all the sheets you have created.  I have run into this same issue before. this includes test sheets youve played with etc. anytime you have added those import functions and not removed them or left them in a state where they will not try to refresh on their own.